# Why can I get user's steps without ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission in my app?

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm making an app to get user's steps by using Google fit.

This is the code.

```
val readRequest = DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .build()

Fitness.getHistoryClient(context, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context))
    .readData(readRequest)
    .addOnSuccessListener { dataReadResponse ->
        Log.d("onSuccess", dataReadResponse)
    }
```

In this doc, The `ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION` permission is required.
https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization#android-10

This is the code to check the permisson.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION)) {
    // NOT_GRANTED
    } else {
    // REJECT
    }
} else {
// GRANTED
}
```

Environment:

```
targetSdkVersion 29
compileSdkVersion 29
running device android10

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:16.0.1'
```

Comment: Did you check what's in `dataReadResponse`? I don't know how this feature behaves without the permission. Maybe it returns a success, but with empty data or an error in the data(?)

Comment: Yes, I checked it again.
In case there is no ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission too, I got the step count.
`2020-12-17 125 step count`

Comment: I gave the permission in app setting.
GRANTED -> NOT_GRANTED
NOT_GRANTED -> GRANTED

Maybe if I allow it once, is the step count available?